# Is it a good practice for a language to allow modifying static variable in non-static context?

Tags: java, php, oop

In term of Object Oriented Programming, Is it a good practice for a language to allow modifying static variable in non-static context?

In Java accessing static variable in non-static context is allowed. For example in the following code, `interest` class variable still can be modified in `MyClass instance1` and `MyClass instance2`.

```
class StaticEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass instance1= new MyClass();
        MyClass instance2= new MyClass();
        // change interest first time
        instance1.interest = 100;
        System.out.println(MyClass.interest);
        System.out.println(instance1.interest);
        System.out.println(instance2.interest);
        // change interest second time
        instance1.interest = 150;
        System.out.println(MyClass.interest);
        System.out.println(instance1.interest);
        System.out.println(instance2.interest);
    }
}
```

`MyClass.java` file:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static int interest = 200;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
100
100
100
150
150
150
```

While in PHP, this is not allowed:

`my_class.php` file:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
  public static $interest = 200;
  public function increase() {
    $this->interest = 500;
  }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->increase();
echo MyClass::$interest;
```

The output `$: php my_class.php`:

**PHP Strict Standards:  Accessing static property MyClass::$interest as non static in /home/petwho/Desktop/java/my_class.php on line 5**

**Strict Standards: Accessing static property MyClass::$interest as non static in /home/petwho/Desktop/java/my_class.php on line 5**

Comment: The questions are, should `interest` be static? Should it be `public`?

Comment: It's not usually a good practice, that's why compilers (eclipse for example) give a warning.